# Asp.Net - MVC - Using a IEnumerable on a Viewmodel return empty model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm starting to learn Asp.net MVC and I'm having problems with make my IEnumerable show on my page.

Right now I'm trying to pass a list of projects on a ViewModel and render a partial view on my layout page.

When I pass the list on a traditional View, it works.
When I pass a single item on a View model, it works too, but when I pass an IENumerator, my model return null.
It's been 3 days that I'm searching for an answer.

Here is my Projeto model

```
    namespace Athena_web.Models
{
public class Projeto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my Projeto Controller

```
using Athena_web.Models;
using Athena_web.ViewModel;

namespace Athena_web.Controllers
{
public class ProjetosController : Controller
{
    // GET: Projetos
    public ActionResult ListaProjetos()
    {
        var projetos = GetProjetos();

        var viewModel = new ProjetosControllerViewModel
        {
            Projetos = projetos
        };

        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
    private IEnumerable<Projeto> GetProjetos()
    {
        return new List<Projeto>
        {
            new Projeto() {Id = 1, Nome = "Projeto A"},
            new Projeto() {Id = 1, Nome = "Projeto 2"},
            new Projeto() {Id = 3, Nome = "Projeto C"}
        };
    }
}
}
```

This is my ProjetosControllerViewModel

```
namespace Athena_web.ViewModel
{
public class ProjetosControllerViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Projeto> Projetos { get; set; }
}
}
```

And this is my view:

```
    @using Athena_web.Controllers
@using Athena_web.Models
@using Athena_web.ViewModel
@model IEnumerable<Athena_web.ViewModel.ProjetosControllerViewModel>
<div class="menuFeature">

<div class="featureProjeto">
    Projetos
</div>

<div class="listaProjetos">
    <ul>
        @if (!Model.Any())
        {
            <li>Cadastre um projeto</li>
        }
        @foreach (var projeto in Model)
        {
            <li>@projeto.Projetos</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my layout page, where I render my partial view

```
<div class="menuLateral">
        <!-- a soma da largura dessa div com a div telaConteudo deve ser de 100%-->
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Projetos/_ListaProjetos.cshtml")

        <div class="menuExtras">
            <!-- essa parte da separado do  menu lateral por questão de posicionamento. Essa parte vai ficar lá embaixo-->
            <div class="mensagemUsuario">
                <!-- coloca o background dessa div como a imagem mensagem.png, background repeat: no-repeat e background-position left-->
                Mensagem
            </div>
            <div class="downloadUsuario">
                <!-- Mesmo esquema de mensagem -->
                Download
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your view expects an `IEnumerable<ProjetosControllerViewModel>`. Instead you are passing an instance of `ProjetosControllerViewModel` that itself is not an `IEnumerable`, but has a property that is. Either pass `viewModel.Projetos` to the view, or change the view to accept `ProjetosControllerViewModel` and then enumerate `Model.Projetos`.

Comment: How are you calling the partial view ?

Comment: I'm calling the partial view this way
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Projetos/_ListaProjetos.cshtml")
(I know it's not the best, but it was the only one that worked)

Comment: @Shyju It seems the problem was the way I render my view.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must accepted view model to ProjetosControllerViewModel in View. Change view code to the following:

```
@model Athena_web.ViewModel.ProjetosControllerViewModel

<div class="menuFeature">
    <div class="featureProjeto">
        Projetos
    </div>

    <div class="listaProjetos">
        <ul>
            @if (!Model.Projetos.Any())
            {
                <li>Cadastre um projeto</li>
            }
            @foreach (var projeto in Model.Projetos)
            {
                <li>@projeto.Id, @projeto.Nome</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also change way that call partial to.repalce this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Projetos/_ListaProjetos.cshtml")
```

With

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ListaProjetos", "Projetos");}
```

Also change partial name from **_ListaProjetos** to **ListaProjetos**

Comment: I changed my code to the one that you gave me, but model still return as null

Comment: where model is null? in View? do you have an error?

Comment: On the view, inside  the foreach model.

Comment: The erros is a System.NullReferenceException, and appears as soon I enter the foreach loop.
Here is the print:
[Print](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGGwEQNdusRMmU1UENueG04VTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It worked! Thank you.
Now I'll edit my question to match your answer (and help others (: )